# How do you replace a method of a Moose object at runtime?

Tags: perl, methods, runtime, moose

Is it possible to replace a method of a Moose object at runtime ?
By looking at the source code of [`Class::MOP::Method`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class::MOP::Method) (which [`Moose::Meta::Method`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Method) inherits from) I concluded that by doing

```
 $method->{body} = sub{ my stuff }
```

I would be able to replace at runtime a method of an object.
I can get the method using

```
 $object->meta->find_method_by_name(<method_name>);
```

However, this didn't quite work out.

Is it conceivable to modify methods at run time? And, what is the way to do it with Moose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moose or not, that does not sound like a good idea.

Instead, design your object to have an accessor for the method. For example, users of your class can use  `My::Frobnicator->frobnicator->()` to get and invoke the `frobnicator` method and use `My::Frobnicator->frobnicator(sub { } )` to set it.

Answer (score 4):

Sinan's idea is a great start.

But with an little extra tweak, you can make using your method accessor just like using a normal method.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;

my $f = Frob->new;

$f->frob(
    sub { 
        my $self = shift;
        print "$self was frobbed\n"; 
        print Carp::longmess('frob') 
    }
);

print "\nCall frob as normal sub\n";
$f->frobit;

print "\nGoto frob\n";
$f->goto_frob;

BEGIN { 
    package Frob;
    use Moose;

    has 'frob' => (
        is => 'rw',
        isa => 'CodeRef',
    );

    sub frobit {
        &{$_[0]->frob};
    }
    sub goto_frob {
        goto $_[0]->frob;
    }

}
```

The two methods in `Frob` are very similar.

- `frobit` passes all arguments, including the invocant to the code ref.
- `goto_frob` passes all arguments, including the invocant to the code ref, and replaces `goto_frob`'s stack frame with the code refs.

Which to use depends on what you want in the stack.

---

Regarding munging the body storage of a `Class::MOP::Method` object, like so `$method->{body} = sub { 'foo' }`:

It's never a good idea to violate encapsulation when you are doing OOP.  Especially not when you are working with complex object systems like Moose and Class::MOP.  It's asking for trouble.  Sometimes, there is no other way to get what you want, but even then, violating encapsulation is still a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415114/how-do-i-make-a-new-moose-class-and-instantiate-an-object-of-that-class-at-runtim/2416863#2416863) mentioned [`MooseX::SingletonMethod`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-SingletonMethod/) you can replace an objects method.

For example:

```
{
    package Foo;
    use MooseX::SingletonMethod;
    sub foo { say 'bar' };
}

my $bar = Foo->new;
my $baz = Foo->new;

# replace foo method just in $baz object
$baz->add_singleton_method( foo => sub { say 'baz' } );

$bar->foo;     # => bar
$baz->foo;     # => baz
```

Also see this SO answer to [What should I do with an object that should no longer be used in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813266/what-should-i-do-with-an-object-that-should-no-longer-be-used-in-perl/817666#817666), which shows how this can be achieved using Moose roles.

/I3az/